# Which nice/deep elaborations on the (operators <-> sheaves) / (endomorphisms <-> objects) theme are there?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, soft-question, sheaf-theory, operator-theory

A linear operator $T:V\to V$ on a (say) vector space over a field $k$ is just a $k[T]$-module, and may be viewed as the sheaf $\mathscr F_T$ over $\mathbb A^1_k$, with fibre over $\lambda\in k$ equal to $V/\langle T(v)-\lambda v\mid v\in V\rangle$; going backwards one may reconstruct $V$ as global sections of $\mathscr F_T$, with $T$ acting via $T(s)(\lambda)=\lambda s(\lambda)$.

This is of course a commonplace observation nowadays, but for some reason I still stay fascinated by this fact, and I learned about it many years ago.

I remember being particularly struck, having shortly before that studied some category theory, by the fact that this construction establishes a connection between endomorphisms in one category and objects in another category, which seemed somewhat unforeseen by category theory.

Later I learned about categories of bordisms, where also an endobordism of an $n$-manifold produces an $n+1$-manifold, but I still have no idea whether this is related in any way to the fact I started with.

[LATER - Re: comment by Will Sawin - this could be in principle formulated in terms of (category-theoretic) traces; however I only know traces of endomorphisms with values **in an object of the same category**, whereas here we seemingly should have traces with values themselves being **objects of another category**]

I've still got a feeling that there is something so deep hidden in this that its deepest roots still wait to be dug out.

In algebraic geometry, this is a simple particular case of the correspondence between modules over a ring and sheaves over the corresponding affine scheme;

The whole spectral theory may be viewed as built on it, things like direct integrals of linear spaces, etc. included;

Various dualities involving vector bundles and projective modules may be also viewed as generalizations of this...

Let me also mention certain "noncommutative" version of the spectrum of a $C^*$-algebra invented by Segal, which I briefly described in an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/182876/41291) to [Why the Dold-Thom theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182823/41291)

But I will stop here and ask my questions.

Does this circle of ideas/facts have a common name?
Which constructions/theories/theorems may be viewed as stemming from it?
Is there a way to describe its place in mathematics?
Is there really a connection between it and the endobordism thing I mentioned?
Is there a category-theoretic or other abstract/axiomatic treatment of similar phenomena?

Comment: The cobordism fact is also a special case of, in a rigid monodical category, the existence of a trace map $\operatorname{Hom}(X,X) \to \operatorname{Hom}(1,1)$,  which you get by composing an endomorphism of $X$ with the duality map $1 \to X \otimes X^{\vee}$, the identity $X^{\vee} \to X^{\vee}$ and the other duality map $X \otimes X^{\vee} \to 1$.

Comment: @WillSawin Good point, but this makes the original thing even more mysterious - it tells that sheaves are analogs of traces, and moreover asks for conditions under which it makes sense to ask whether the whole category is "equivalent" to $\text{Hom}(1,1)$.

Answer (score 8):

What you describe in the opening of your question is most naturally an equivalence of categories, not some dimension-shifting thing between endomorphisms and objects as you suggest.  Indeed, let $\mathcal C$ be a category.  The *category of endomorphisms* in $\mathcal C$ is the functor category $\mathcal C^{\circlearrowleft}$, where $\circlearrowleft = \mathrm B \mathbb N$ denotes the category with one object and endomorphism monoid $\mathbb N$, i.e. the category freely generated by an object with an endomorphism.  In some corners of category theory, $\circlearrowleft$ would be called "the walking endomorphism".  In particular, it is a category, being a category of functors.

If $\mathcal C$ is a nice enough monoidal category ($\mathrm{Vect}$ is nice enough), then $\mathcal C^{\circlearrowleft}$ can also be described as the category of $\mathcal C$-linear functors from the free $\mathcal C$-linearization of $\circlearrowleft$.  This is the $\mathcal C$-enriched category with one object and endomorphism algebra $\mathbf 1_{\mathcal C}[x] \in \mathcal C$, the "polynomial algebra" in one variable with coefficients in the unit object $\mathbf 1_{\mathcal C} \in \mathcal C$.

But to move to your more geometric questions requires more than just this elementary category theory.  For example, it happens that $\mathbf 1_{\mathcal C}[x]$ is a commutative algebra, and so its spectrum is an affine variety.  This would not hold if $\circlearrowleft$ were replaced by some other more complicated walking object, say if you were asking about pairs of endomorphisms and not just endomorphisms.  (On the other hand, $\circlearrowleft \times \circlearrowleft$ is the walking pair of *commuting* endomorphisms.)

I don't think there's anything deeper to your observation about endobordisms except to observe that $\mathcal C^{\circlearrowleft}$, being a functor category, is naturally a category.

Actually, there's something else to say about bordisms.  The category of bordisms is naturally a double category, i.e. a category object internal to categories.  Bordisms and their compositions form the "horizontal" morphisms but the "vertical" morphisms are smooth functions.  (Important variations: use just embeddings or just local diffeomorphisms.)  In any double category, if you fix an object, you get a category whose objects are the horizontal endomorphisms of that object.  In the case of $\emptyset \in \mathrm{Bord}$, you get the category of $n$-manifolds and smooth maps (or embeddings or local diffeomorphisms).

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. The question was certainly too vague to argue about anything, but let me still name two deeper facts that I miss incorporated in your picture: (1) sheaves that I mention in the beginning are "over $k$ itself viewed as a variety", to make sense of $T(s)\lambda=\lambda s(\lambda)$; (2) representation-theoretic viewpoint, - according to it, the sheaf formed arises from decomposing a representation of $\mathbb N$ into indecomposables, so may be viewed as a "map" from $\mathbb A^1$ to the "space" of those indecomposables

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Well, from the point of view of $\mathcal C^{\circlearrowleft}$, the "global sections" functor is the evaluation at the object in $\circlearrowleft$, and your coordinate $\lambda$ on $\mathbb A^1$ is the evaluation at the arrow in $\circlearrowleft$.

Comment: But I worry I might have given a wrong impression in my answer above.  I don't think I've satisfactorially explained everything in the relationship between $\circlearrowleft$ and the affine line $\mathbb A^1$.  Certainly "sheaves on $\mathbb A^1$" are "functors from $\mathbb A^1$ to $\mathrm{Vect}$", if the latter can be defined, so it really is just to identify $\circlearrowleft$ with $\mathbb A^1$.  I think of this identification as being a sort of Pontrjagin duality --- it's _not_ an equivalence of "geometric" objects, just like the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(A,1)$ is not the Pontrjagin ...

Comment: ... dual group to $A$, but is somehow related to it.  (One could say they are "Morita equivalent".)  So there's some element of geometry that provides this "duality" that elementary category theory can describe, but wouldn't predict.

Comment: You can try to make a little headway towards extracting $\mathbb A^1$ from $\circlearrowleft$, although I wouldn't have thought to do this without going and looking for the connection.  Namely, the topology of $\mathbb A^1$ has to do with where the endomorphism is or is not invertible.  If $\mathcal C$ is nice enough, then you can try to extract "blocks" from $\mathcal C^{\circlearrowleft}$ generated under extensions by individual simples.  These subcategories correspond to the basic closed sets, and the quotient categories to a (sub)basis of opens.

Comment: The reason I find this less than a complete story, though, is the following. (This is closely related to the Pontrjagin vs Eilenberg-MacLane difference mentioned above.) Suppose that $\mathcal C$ is symmetric monoidal. Then the natural symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathcal C^{\circlearrowleft}$ corresponds, on the $\mathbb A^1$ side, to tensoring together spaces of global sections.  This is the "convolution" tensor product for the additive group $\mathbb A^1$.  The natural tensor structure on $\mathrm{Sheaves}(\mathbb A^1)$, on the other hand, is the fiberwise one --- at least, that's ...

Comment: ... most natural is you think of $\mathbb A^1$ as a "space" (and not an abelian group).  I don't see how pure category theory would ever come up with the fiberwise product from $\mathcal C^\circlearrowleft$ out of thin air --- it seems to require instead some external intervention. See, Tannakianism provides a functorial way to extract a space from its sheaves _as a symmetric monoidal category_, but not as a bare category (Gabriel's reconstruction theorem notwithstanding), just like you cannot extract an affine scheme from its _vector space_ of functions.